# Run time error: how to short the code within one loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am solving a problem  I m getting a runtime error and if there is any other error and we can shorten the length of code, please suggest

```py
T=int(input())

for i in range(T):
    N= int(input())
    P=[0]*N

    C=list(map(int,input().split()))
    H=list(map(int,input().split()))
    for i in range(N):
        if((i-C[i]>=0)and (i+C[i]<N)):
                for j in range(i-C[i],i+C[i]+1):
                    P[j]=P[j]+1
        elif((i-C[i]>=0)and (i+C[i]>N)):
                for j in range(i-C[i],N):
                    P[j]=P[j]+1




        elif((i+C[i]<N) and (i-C[i]<0)) :
                for j in range(0,i+C[i]+1):
                    P[j]=P[j]+1
        else:
                for j in range(0,N):
                    P[j]=P[j]+1
    H=sorted(H)
    P=sorted(P)
    if(H==P):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same looping variable for test cases and for an array.
use any other variable in the loop of test cases then you will not get the Runtime error.